# Angular Shared Service - when adding an item to list, shared service is duplicating data

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I'm learning Angular and need your help :).

I've two components list-items and list-item.

1. list-items shows the list of items
2. list-item is to add a new list item.

When I add a list item on list-item and navigate back to list-items, the shared service's list of items has duplicate items. To put it in simple terms, when I add one list item, I see multiple duplicate items in the list-items screen. GitHub link for the sample project to replicate the issue is @  https://github.com/ChathaKiran/AngularSharedServiceIssue. Below is snapshot of my code. Please let me know how can I make sure there are no duplicates.

Shared Service

```
export class AppService {
  private listItem = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  listItemObservable = this.listItem.asObservable();

  private listItems = new BehaviorSubject([] as string[]);
  listItemsObservable = this.listItems.asObservable();

  updateListItem(_listItem: string) {
    this.listItem.next(_listItem);
  }

  updateListItems(_listItems: string[]) {
    this.listItems.next(_listItems);
  }
}
```

List Items Component

```
export class ListItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  _localListItems: string[];

  constructor(private appService: AppService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.appService.listItemsObservable.subscribe(_listItems => {
      this._localListItems = _listItems;
    });

    this.appService.listItemObservable.subscribe(_listItem => {
      if (_listItem != undefined) {
        var allItems = this._localListItems.concat(_listItem);
        this.appService.updateListItems(allItems);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

List Item Component

```
export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  listItemName: string;

  constructor(private maintenanceWindowService: AppService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  btnAddListItem(){
    this.maintenanceWindowService.updateListItem(this.listItemName);

    this.router.navigate(['list-items']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have to unsubscribe from your Observables.
Read this [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0) and update your code using ngOnDestroy, where you will `.unsubscribe()` from your Observable, or add some pipeable operator like `.pipe(take(1))`.
Read more here [Piepable operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators)

Comment: Bingo. That fixed the issue. Thanks a ton.